# Hashtable with linked list not work in c?

Tags: c, memory, linked-list, hashtable

I've a problem with memory allocation for an hash table with linked list (for avoid collisions) in C.

I think that the problem is on allocation of an item.
I've made two scruct, one for the single item and one for the table.
The first have two pointer to next and prev item.
Please help me.
I stay on this code until 3 days.
The code :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define CAPACITY 50000 

unsigned long hash(char *str) { 
    unsigned long int stringsum = 0; 
    for(; *str != '\0'; str++) { 
        stringsum += *str; 
    } 
    return stringsum % CAPACITY; 
    
} 


typedef struct item  { 
    char *value; 
    char *key; 
    struct item *next; 
    struct item *prev; 
} ht_item; 

typedef struct hashtable { 
    ht_item **items; 
    int dim; 
    int count; 
} HashTable; 

HashTable* create_table(int size); HashTable* create_item(HashTable *table, char *value, char *key); 
void print_table(HashTable* table, int dim); 


int main(void) { 
    HashTable *table = create_table(CAPACITY); 
    table = create_item(table, "Giuseppe", "Nome"); 
    print_table(table, CAPACITY); 
    return 0; 
    
} 


HashTable* create_item(HashTable *table, char *value, char *key) { 
    unsigned long index = hash(key);
    printf("%u", index); 
    ht_item *_iterator; ht_item *prev;
    for(_iterator = table->items[index], prev = NULL; _iterator != NULL; prev = _iterator, _iterator = _iterator->next);
     _iterator = (ht_item*)malloc(sizeof(ht_item));
     _iterator->key = (char*)malloc(200);
     _iterator->value = (char*)malloc(200); 
     strcpy(_iterator->key, key);
     strcpy(_iterator->value, value);
     _iterator->next = NULL;
     _iterator->prev = prev; 
    return table; 
} 


HashTable* create_table(int size)
{ 
    HashTable *table = (HashTable*)malloc(sizeof(HashTable));
    table->dim = size; 
    table->items = (ht_item**)calloc(size, sizeof(ht_item*)); 
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){ 
        table->items[i] = NULL; 
    } 
    
    return table; 
} 


void print_table(HashTable* table, int dim) { 
    for(int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++)
     { 
        if(table->items[i] != NULL)
         { ht_item *_iterator = (ht_item*)malloc(sizeof(ht_item));
             for(_iterator = table->items[i]; _iterator != NULL;
             _iterator = _iterator->next)
             { 
                printf("Key: %s\tValue: %s\n", _iterator->key, _iterator->value); 
                } free(_iterator); 
            } 
        } 
}
```

Comment: Um.. look at your `create_item` function and consider this: you use that for-loop to find the last entry in the collision chain, storing a pointer to said-same`_iterator`. Now, what is the *first* thing you do after that loop? What do you think `_iterator = (ht_item*)malloc(sizeof(ht_item));` is going to do to the `_iterator` variable value you just worked so hard (and completely unnecessarily, btw) to find? Run your code in a debugger and step through that function, watching what the table looks like when done. The actual table is unmodified and all your effort is wasted (and memory leaked).

Comment: @WhozCraig OP is also keeping a copy of `_iterator` in `prev`.

Comment: No `->next` is ever assigned. @OP work on a proper implementation of a linked list first, before working on a hash table. For example, there is no reason to iterate over all nodes in a linked list to find the last, if it's a doubly linked list. It also doesn't have to be a doubly linked list, you can also just insert new nodes at the head end.

Comment: I use iterator for find the last element. Then I allocate the memory for the block pointed from iterator (the element that I want to insert).

Comment: I use prev for keep the element before _iterator so that it points to the prev pointer of the ht_item object

Comment: Copy the string arguments to `->key` and `->value` using `strdup` or `strndup` rather than wasting memory space and risking buffer overflows.

Comment: The hash function doesn't need to know about the capacity. The `% CAPACITY` is misplaced, move that to the create_item function: `unsigned long index = hash(key) % table->dim`.

Comment: The `print_table` function doesn't need the `dim` argument. It can just do `for(int i = 0; i < table->dim; i++)` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some changes in your code. Please read through the blocks containing `// CHANGE HERE` comment.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define CAPACITY 50000

// CHANGE HERE - additional parameter, value to be used for modulo
unsigned long hash(char *str, unsigned int mod_value) { 
    unsigned long int stringsum = 0; 
    for(; *str != '\0'; str++) { 
        stringsum += *str; 
    }
    // CHANGE HERE - use mod_value instead of CAPACITY
    return stringsum % mod_value; 
    
} 


typedef struct item  { 
    char *value; 
    char *key; 
    struct item *next; 
    struct item *prev; 
} ht_item; 

typedef struct hashtable { 
    ht_item **items; 
    int dim; 
    int count; 
} HashTable; 

HashTable* create_table(int size); HashTable* create_item(HashTable *table, char *value, char *key); 
void print_table(HashTable* table, int dim); 


int main(void) { 
    HashTable *table = create_table(CAPACITY); 
    table = create_item(table, "Giuseppe", "Nome"); 
    print_table(table); 
    return 0; 
} 


HashTable* create_item(HashTable *table, char *value, char *key) {
    // CHANGE HERE - function arguments validation
    if (table == NULL)
    {
        return table;
    }
    if (value == NULL || key == NULL)
    {
        printf("Key or value is null\n");
        return table;
    }

    // CHANGE HERE - pass table->dim to hash
    unsigned long index = hash(key, table->dim);
    printf("Index: %lu\n", index);
    
    // CHANGE HERE - simplified the code a bit
    ht_item* new_node = malloc(sizeof(ht_item));
    new_node->key = malloc(200 * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(new_node->key, key, 200);
    new_node->value = malloc(200 * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(new_node->value, value, 200);
    
    // CHANGE HERE - if first node in index
    if (table->items[index] == NULL)
    {
        table->items[index] = new_node;
        return table;
    }
    
    ht_item *cur, *prev = NULL;
    for(cur = table->items[index]; cur != NULL; prev = cur, cur = cur->next);
    
    prev->next = new_node;  // CHANGE HERE - it seems this line was missing
    new_node->prev = prev;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    
    return table; 
} 


HashTable* create_table(int size)
{ 
    HashTable *table = (HashTable*)malloc(sizeof(HashTable));
    table->dim = size; 
    table->items = (ht_item**)calloc(size, sizeof(ht_item*)); 
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){ 
        table->items[i] = NULL; 
    } 
    
    return table; 
} 


void print_table(HashTable* table) {
    // CHANGE HERE - function arguments validation
    if (table == NULL)
    {
        printf("Table is null\n");
        return;
    }
    // CHANGE HERE - change CAPACITY to dim
    for(int i = 0; i < table->dim; i++)
    {
        //printf("i = %d [%d]\n", i, table->items[i] == NULL);
        if(table->items[i] != NULL)
        {
            // CHANGE HERE - removed unnecessary malloc
            ht_item *_iterator = NULL;
            for(_iterator = table->items[i]; _iterator != NULL; _iterator = _iterator->next)
            { 
                printf("Key: %s\tValue: %s\n", _iterator->key, _iterator->value);
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please explain every `CHANGE HERE`. Why change? What was the error? Also please explain why a function named `print_table` destroys the table by freeing all keys and values stored therein, and some but not all nodes.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem., edited those comments and included the details. About `print_table` I assumed it was the author's intent to free up the memory.

Comment: How print table destroy all?

Comment: `if (table == NULL)` is just a safety check. The main changes are `if (table->items[index] == NULL)`, `prev->next = new_node;` and inside `print_table`, `ht_item *_iterator = NULL;`

Comment: No, the author intent was obscured by allocating a completely unnecessary `struct item` and then promptly forgetting about it. OP obviously assumed that `free` in the end is a natural pair to that `malloc` (it isn't).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem., aah, yeah you are right. I did the necessary edits.

Comment: Also `prev->next = new_node` will fail if there are no items in the current bucket and `prev` is NULL.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem., that's already handled, above the for loop there is a condition `if (table->items[index] == NULL)`

Comment: sorry missed it

Comment: The `->prev` member is unused and thus useless. And appending at the end of a singularly linked list is a waste of resources since in a hash table the order of nodes usually doesn't matter. Just allocating a new node, assigning node->next to the first node at an index, then replacing the first node by the new node, always works, even if there's a NULL pointer at the hash index. The real problem here is OP not grasping linked lists. And this answer is hardly addressing that.

Comment: Cheatah,  Do you intend to add the new node directly to the top of the list without scrolling it?

Comment: @Cheatah, the intent of this answer was to point out some issues in OP's code and ways to resolve those issues. OP may have some use case for which he may require `prev` but hasn't implemented that because the basic code had some issues. Removing `prev` in this case would have been against OP's intent.

Comment: In fact I didn't think about adding the knot at the beginning as cheatah is saying (if I understand correctly). Regarding the free in the print list it actually deallocated the table.
I try to fix everything and see if it works

Comment: @aocLEL, I have already edited the `print_table` function, please check.

Comment: If we are considering OP's intent, the use of the `dim` argument in the `print_table` function is a poor improvement. The `table` struct already has a `dim` member that is assigned upon creation. That should be used both for the `print_table` function as for the `create_item` function directly operating on the hash function return value (see my answer and other comments). The `dim` argument to the `print_table` function should be dropped.

Comment: @Cheetah, Yeah, that makes sense to use `table->dim` instead. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `create_item` function can and should be simplified.
I have put some comments inline.

```
HashTable* create_item(HashTable *table, char *value, char *key) { 
    // use modulo operator here, not in the hash function
    unsigned long index = hash(key) % table->dim;

    // nicer way of allocating
    ht_item *insert = malloc(sizeof *insert);

    // use strdup to avoid wasted memory and buffer overflows
    insert->key = strdup(key);
    insert->value = strdup(value);

    // head insert rather than tail
    insert->next = table->items[index];
    table->items[index] = insert;        

    return table; 
}
```

I dropped the use of the `prev` member. If you need that somewhere it's an exercise for you to add it. I don't think it's necessary for a simple hash table.

Comment: See my comments on the original question for some additional improvements.